# Est-ce que l'expression "Je paierais cher pour" est utilisée ici littéralement ou figurativement ?

Tags: sens, expressions

> "Je **paierais cher pour** que tu acceptes de dîner avec moi."

Je sais pas si cette personne veut dire littéralement qu'il paierait volontiers même une somme folle pour que son souhait se réalise,  ou s'il s'agit plutôt d'une hyperbole figurativement utilisée dans la même veine que "Qu'est-ce que je ne donnerais pas pour".

Answer (score 3):

Il me semble que c'est plutôt la deuxième, c'est à dire dans le sens figuré de l'expression:

> Qu'est-ce que je ne donnerais pas pour que tu acceptes de dîner avec
>   moi!

Mais sans avoir plus de contexte, c'est difficile de répondre. Cependant, cette expression est rarement utilisée dans son sens littéral.

Comment: Dans le sens littéral, on dira plutôt: "je serais prêt à payer pour que tu acceptes de dîner avec moi" ou "je suis prêt à mettre le prix".

Answer (score 1):

"Je paierai cher pour" est effectivement une expression pour signifier que le locuteur a extrêmement envie de faire quelque chose. On peut effectivement le considérer comme un synonyme de "Qu'est-ce que je donnerai pas pour" ou encore "Qu'est-ce que je ferai pas pour". Faute de contexte, il vaut mieux privilégier votre deuxième interprétation.

Answer (score 1):

En fait c'est un peu les deux à la fois, ce n'est pas entièrement une hyperbole. Le sujet se dit prêt à faire des efforts pour obtenir ce qui lui est... cher. L'expression « payer cher » n'indique pas forcément de l'argent, mais implique néanmoins un coût, et on peut payer en nature, payer de sa personne, etc. Donc vous voyez, les mots de prix, coût, payer, cher, etc. sont tous utilisables pour discuter de la situation dans laquelle se trouve le sujet. Dans le cas d'une hyperbole, on serait vite limité dans l'analogie (il est fort comme un ours: donc il a une truffe et des griffes?).